# Looking for ideas on having two custom Teams apps w/ SSO to be in the same app manifest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

We have a 2 custom teams applications. 1 is internally developed .NET Core application with SSO and the other is .NET Framework using the the Teams SDK developed and hosted by a third-party also using SSO. So, they are in two different domains.

We would like to have both of these applications be in one Teams App manifest, however the webApplicationInfo can only point to one domain.

```
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "«ClientId»",
    "resource": "api://«Domain»/«ClientId»"
  }
```

If the domain in resource is ours, then the 3rd-party application returns:

```
App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match
```

And the same occurs with our application if we point the webapplicationinfo to the third party domain.

I'm looking for a way for these two applications to co-exist within the same Teams manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The resource element is used to ensure that the authentication request using `getAuthToken()` is from the domain given in the app manifest. This means that the resource element is tied to a specific domain, and it's not possible to specify multiple domains in this property.

Therefore, if you have two apps that are hosted on different domains, you would need to create separate Teams app manifests for each app. Each manifest would have its own webApplicationInfo property with the id and resource elements specific to the app and its domain.

For more info, refer [webApplicationInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#webapplicationinfo).